Is there a series containing all modular residues?
Does there exist any sequence faster than a linear sequence (Difference between two terms is greater than O(n)) such that for all $n, m<n$, there exists infinitely many i such that $a(i)$ $mod$ $n = m$.
In other words, for any sequence of the form $s(n) = an + b$ for integer $a$ and natural number $b$, infinitely many terms of sequence s should appear in sequence a.
For example I thought that the fibbonaci sequence would satisfy this as it is periodic modulo n, but it does not contain all possible remainders in its period for all numbers. (Eg: For the fibbonaci sequence modulo 11, 4 never appears).
Note: I do not care for it to be exactly periodic, as long as I can always guarantee that a certain modulo would appear again regardless of where I am in the series.

What means „ faster than a linear series‚

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

You can check that the sequence defined by $a_i = i! + i$ has this property.
It already grows pretty fast, but it's easy to make it grow faster by adding more exclamation points....
